# Does java version "1.6.0_65" equivocate to java 6?

Tags: java, macos

On OS X (10.6.8) and in terminal:

```
java -version
```

returns

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

Is this actually Java 6?

I'm guessing that the version of Java in 10.6.8 is at least relatively current.

I'm asking because of planning to install jMeter.

Comment: Yes. Java versions 1.x.* are often shortened to just version x.

Comment: Yup, it sure does. Since Java 1.5/5 they changed the naming convention.

Comment: Wikipedia has a fairly thorough article on [Java version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. That clears up the question I regret asking. Will be less hasty next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Java 1.2, Java started being called by the number after the decimal point. So, Java 1.2 was Java 2 and kept that name until version 1.5 at which point it was called Java 5.  Then, 1.6.x was called Java 6.

1.7.x is called Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 1.6.x is Java 6.

As to whether 1.6.0_65 can be considered "relatively current", yes and no. It's a relatively current release *of Java 6* (see the [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6_.28December_11.2C_2006.29)). However, Java 6 itself dates back to 2006 and is two generations old.